# Flutter get language strings within a widget without changing context locale

Tags: flutter

I have been able to implement multiple language support in Flutter using the developer docs (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

I was wondering if there is a way to access the language strings we define within a widget but by **not changing the locale of the context**.

Here is my use case.

I am presenting a set of books as a grid of cards. The content is of different languages (e.g. English and Spanish). Now, based on the language I would like to use some of the text strings from the locale just for one card of the grid.

For example, if the data of each book is: language (en, es), title (...), no_pages (x). Then, when presenting the grid I would like to use the word "pages" from the string either as "Pages" or "Pagina".

How does one go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the language_builder package in pub.dev It is very easy to use. By wrapping your root widget with LanguageBuilder you can configure your app's language. Tell your app to use the phones' language or change it manually from the app.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Language Builder Example',
      home: LanguageBuilder(
        useDeviceLanguage: false,
        defaultLanguage: 'en',
        languagesMap: Languages.languages,
        child: MainPage(),
        //splash: Container(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Languages {
  static Map<String, String> languages = {
    "tr": """{
        "main_page": {
            "title": "Ana Sayfa",
            "second_page": "İkinci Sayfa"
        },
        "second_page": {
            "title": "İkinci Sayfa",
            "main_page": "Ana Sayfa",
            "message":"Bu sayfa 2. sayfadır."
        }
    }""",
    "en": """{
        "main_page": {
            "title": "Main Page",
            "second_page": "Second Page"
        },
        "second_page": {
            "title": "Second Page",
            "main_page": "Main Page",
            "message":"This is 2nd page."
        }
    }""",
    "de": """{
        "main_page": {
            "title": "Hauptseite",
            "second_page": "Zweite Seite"
        },
        "second_page": {
            "title": "Zweite Seite",
            "main_page": "Hauptseite",
            "message":"Dies ist die 2. Seite."
        }
    }"""
  };
}

//MainPage
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
        LanguageBuilder.texts['main_page']['title'],
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can configure the example above for your case. For more info take a  look at language_builder:

[language_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/language_builder)

Comment: Thanks @aedemirsen. Let me try this soon